# CSS Rounded corner in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I wanted to make my top left hand corner of a table rounded in all browsers.

I tried this:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;

-moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;

border-top-left-radius: 9px;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working in Google chrome. Can anyone see the error? I'm also sure it used to work...

Comment: Inspect the element and see whether styles are being overridden.

Comment: can you inspect the element that should have the rounded corner? Like Christoph said, there may be another rule overriding this one

Comment: right-click -> inspect element, check on the right panel if the CSS rule has a line through it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the padding to 5 and back to 0 and it seemed to work again... must be the cache or something, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

```
border-top-left-radius:9px;
```

or

```
border-radius:9px 0 0;
```

works. If not it's a problem in your css - probably some other style-declaration with higher specificity overriding this rule.

Answer (score 0):

It should work: `border-top-left-radius: 9px;`

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [border-radus.com](http://border-radius.com/), it'll generate the css for you. If that doesn't work there's a huge chance that the CSS is being overwritten elsewhere.